# Django: Add a "configuration" list for different code sections to access

Tags: python, django

I use these different code snippets at different parts in my code. To avoid potential errors over time I would like to implement one configuration list that both these sections can access. The list gets longer over time with more entries. Do you have an idea about how to achieve that?

Here the "configuration" list #1 and #2 should access in order to perform the `filter` and `if` statement:

```
list = [TYPE_OF_PEOPLE_ATTENDING, HEARING_ABOUT_THE_EVENT, MISSING_EVENT_INFORMATION, REASON_FOR_ATTENDING]
```

## 1

```
entities = (
    Entity.objects.values("answer__question__focus", "name")
    .annotate(count=Count("pk"))
    .annotate(total_salience=Sum("salience"))
    .filter(
        Q(answer__question__focus=QuestionFocus.TYPE_OF_PEOPLE_ATTENDING) |
        Q(answer__question__focus=QuestionFocus.HEARING_ABOUT_THE_EVENT) |
        Q(answer__question__focus=QuestionFocus.MISSING_EVENT_INFORMATION) |
        Q(answer__question__focus=QuestionFocus.REASON_FOR_ATTENDING)
    )
)
```

## 2

```
if (
    answer_obj.question.focus == QuestionFocus.TYPE_OF_PEOPLE_ATTENDING
    or answer_obj.question.focus == QuestionFocus.HEARING_ABOUT_THE_EVENT
    or answer_obj.question.focus == QuestionFocus.MISSING_EVENT_INFORMATION
    or answer_obj.question.focus == QuestionFocus.REASON_FOR_ATTENDING
):
    entities = analyze_entities(answer_obj.answer)
    bulk_create_entities(entities, response, answer_obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite both statements to directly use a list:

```
VALID_TYPES = [TYPE_OF_PEOPLE_ATTENDING, HEARING_ABOUT_THE_EVENT, MISSING_EVENT_INFORMATION, REASON_FOR_ATTENDING]
```

1

```
entities = (
    Entity.objects.values("answer__question__focus", "name")
    .annotate(count=Count("pk"))
    .annotate(total_salience=Sum("salience"))
    .filter(answer__question__focus__in=VALID_TYPES)
```

2

```
if (answer_obj.question.focus in VALID_TYPES):
    entities = analyze_entities(answer_obj.answer)
    bulk_create_entities(entities, response, answer_obj)
```